# Stanford NLP RuntimeIOException

Tags: java, maven, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to do some sentiment analysis using Stanford NLP in Java. I'm using Maven, but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "/home/amos/CPP/2016/Hadoop/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "/home/amos/CPP/2016/Hadoop/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:182)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.loadModel(ParserAnnotator.java:187)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.<init>(ParserAnnotator.java:107)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.parse(AnnotatorImplementations.java:132)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$10.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:420)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:289)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
    at nl.uva.cpp.WordCountMapper.create_pipeline(WordCountMapper.java:68)
    at nl.uva.cpp.WordCountMapper.map(WordCountMapper.java:73)
    at nl.uva.cpp.WordCountMapper.map(WordCountMapper.java:22)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "/home/amos/CPP/2016/Hadoop/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:448)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:310)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:179)
    ... 20 more
```

I am not sure what to do. I've downloaded Stanford CoreNLP from [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/), but I am not sure where I should extract it.

I also added

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

to my `pom.xml` file, and it started downloading when running `mvn package`, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: extract the jars to your project folder. something like projectPath/lib

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hadoop, you can use java fat jar of your project by using [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html)

After building the project (mvn package) it will create one single jar with all dependencies merged into it.You need to put your hadoop driver class as mainClass here like

```
 <transformer> implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
<mainClass>your-driver-class</mainClass>
</transformer>
```